# Django rest framework PUT slow on large model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am updating an **entire** Django model through the DRF API. The model has a large number of entries (> 2000). So far I have been doing the following:

```
import requests
for i in range(max_display):
    payload = {'a':name[i],'b':surname[i],'c':email[i]}
    r = requests.put('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/list/' + str(i+1) + '/', data=payload)
```

But this loop is slow. I was wondering if there was a way to dump the whole database into the DRF API. Something where I can update all the `a` keys by the whole `name` vector without having to use a slow loop.

I think this should be possible since I am updating all the model and I do not have unchanged exceptions.

`name, surname, and email` are vectors of length `max_display`.

Comment: Have you considered making a custom endpoint and upserting directly to the db with SQL? That way you can update all 2000+ models in one transaction.

Comment: could you please refer to  a way to do this? I am fairly new to web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the django model through model.objects.get(id=id), it is way much faster.